# Salesforce - setting checkbox values on the Lead screen upon creation from an ExactTarget Landing page

Tags: marketing-cloud, web2lead, landing-page

I have an ExactTarget Landing page form that customers will use to fill out and submit requests for products. At the bottom of the form are two opt-in questions that correspond to existing out-of-the-box fields in SFDC.

The fields in SF = HasOptedOutOfEmail and HasOptedOutOfFax

I have two radio button field sets named the same in my Landing Page form, and I can see that they are passing either '1' or '0' when submitted, however, nothing is checked or modified in the new Lead that is created with each test submission.

Can someone verify that '1' or '0' are the values that should be passed? Is there anything else I need to look for?

[image]

thanks for your time!

Comment: I don't think those are Radio buttons.  I think they are checkboxes.  If other stuff is updating correclty, I'm guessing a plain 1/0 don't work.  Try passing true/false or 'true' and 'false' (string versions).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this question - [Some boolean values are 0/1 and some are true/false](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/22810/some-boolean-values-are-0-1-and-some-are-true-false)

Some values will be 0/1, and some will be true/false.

I would use `true` and `false` in this case, and not `0` or `1`.